# How does one decode Base64?

Tags: encoding, base64, decode, binary-data, radix

As seen [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2566130), they have the line `ZG9udGJlYWhhdGVyc3RhcnR1cCtoYWNrZXJuZXdzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==`.

How would one go about decoding this line of Base64?

Comment: Oh, interesting way to filter for candidates.

Comment: I think that’s a challenge *you* need to master.

Comment: They mention wanting to see your stackoverflow ID. I wouldn't give it to them if I were you!

Comment: Interesting way to avoid getting your mail crawled.

Answer (score 5):

Base64-decode it. For example, put it in this online decoder: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/

BTW this is not encryption, it's encoding.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple base64 encoding, one way to decode it is to use openssl

```
echo 'ZG9udGJlYWhhdGVyc3RhcnR1cCtoYWNrZXJuZXdzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==' | openssl base64 -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a base64 decoder. Or - specify a language you would like to use and I can give you some example code.

BTW: I decoded this using this online decoder:

http://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/Base64Decode

It decodes to

dontbeahaterstartup+hackernews@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoding is explained here: [Base64 decoder](http://www.base64online.com)

```
ZG9udGJlYWhhdGVyc3RhcnR1cCtoYWNrZXJuZXdzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== => dontbeahaterstartup+hackernews@gmail.com
```